# Trying to create a swipe to confirm button in Swift Ui

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

So, I saw many swipe to buy buttons around the web and on many apps. I thought it would be good to implement onto my app. But for some reason, the ZStack isn't functioning properly, the background is on top of the swipe arrow. I can't properly place it inside of another view. Furthermore, how would one perform an action when the swipable arrow is fully at the end?

```
 

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewState = CGSize(width: 0, height: 50)

    var body: some View {
     
        
        ZStack{
            
/// This part is the background of the swipe to buy 

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .offset(x: viewState.width)
                .frame(width: 800,height: 100)
            
            HStack{
                
// This part is the actual swiping arrow 

                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .offset(x: viewState.width)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                                viewState = value.translation
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                    viewState = .zero
                                }
                            }
                    )
                    
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .offset(x: viewState.width)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                                viewState = value.translation
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                    viewState = .zero
                                }
                            }
                    )

                }
                
                
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }
            
            
  
            
        
       
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **ZStack** is working fine, the **issue** is you are giving the **top RoundedRectangle** fix **width = 800** and you use **Spacer()** to push the HStack to the leading side. You have to **remove** this width in order to work this fine, like this:

```
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .offset(x: viewState.width)
        .frame(height: 100)
```

**But** if you want fix **width** you can use **background()** instead of **ZStack**, like this:

```
   HStack{

       ZStack {

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                 .fill(Color.blue)
                 .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                 .offset(x: viewState.width)
                 .gesture(
                     DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                          viewState = value.translation
                     }
                          .onEnded { value in
                              withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                 viewState = .zero
                              }
                          }
                   )

            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                .offset(x: viewState.width)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                         viewState = value.translation
                    }
                         .onEnded { value in
                              withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                   viewState = .zero
                              }
                         }
                 )

              }

             Spacer()
          }.background(

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .offset(x: viewState.width)
                .frame(width: 800,height: 100)
        )
```